# what's the meaning of early in this sentence?

Tags: adjectives, vocabulary

Look at this sentence from a Toefl reading exam:

> Other researchers go even further, suggesting that the data provide evidence for large open expanses of water on the early Martian surface.

Here the adjective "early" comes before a noun. Isn't "early" an adjective for showing time and stating that an event is happening near the beginning of a particular period?
What's the meaning of "early surface"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dictionary definition of 'early':

> belonging or happening near the beginning of a particular period.

The "early martian surface" means the surface of the planet in its early period, perhaps at what is believed to be the beginning of its existence.